Question regarding UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout
I am studying with the STM32F103RB, and there's something I don't understand.
In the function below, I noticed that it checks for an overrun in UART after confirming that the RXNE flag is 0 (which means there is no data to receive in the RDR). I think this is strange because an overrun should occur when RXNE is set.
Is there something that I misunderstood?
// below function was called with this : UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(huart, UART_FLAG_RXNE, RESET, tickstart, Timeout) != HAL_OK)
static HAL_StatusTypeDef UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint32_t Flag, FlagStatus Status,
                                                     uint32_t Tickstart, uint32_t Timeout)
{
  /* Wait until flag is set */
  while ((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, Flag) ? SET : RESET) == Status)
  {
    /* Check for the Timeout */
    if (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
    {
      if (((HAL_GetTick() - Tickstart) > Timeout) || (Timeout == 0U))
      {

        return HAL_TIMEOUT;
      }

      if ((READ_BIT(huart->Instance->CR1, USART_CR1_RE) != 0U) && (Flag != UART_FLAG_TXE) && (Flag != UART_FLAG_TC))
      {
        if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_ORE) == SET)
        {
          /* Clear Overrun Error flag*/
          __HAL_UART_CLEAR_OREFLAG(huart);

          /* Blocking error : transfer is aborted
          Set the UART state ready to be able to start again the process,
          Disable Rx Interrupts if ongoing */
          UART_EndRxTransfer(huart);

          huart->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_ORE;

          /* Process Unlocked */
          __HAL_UNLOCK(huart);

          return HAL_ERROR;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return HAL_OK;
}


Aside: consider avoiding subtraction with uncontrolled uint32_t: (HAL_GetTick() - Tickstart) > Timeout --> HAL_GetTick() > (Timeout + Tickstart).

__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, Flag) ? SET : RESET uses a ?: to form the result.  Why does __HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_ORE) not do the same?

while ((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, Flag) ? SET : RESET) == Status)
This will be
while ((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_RXNE) ? SET : RESET) == RESET)
So if you consider it will loop till the RXNE is 1 (which means RX data is available to read) or timeout happen in the Receive function. I hope this is what you are asking.

The overrun will happen when there are multiple data in the FIFO than it can handle. (You are right it will only happen when the RXNE is set). However it will happen if there are multiple bytes, where the number of bytes exceeds the FIFO depth

@chux Your "correction" of the tick calculation will not work when the ticks wrap around. The common solution is the original version. Yes, it needs a prove that it works for the target with the used tool chain.

@Harshit awesome ! so that is for checking if there are multiple byte data bigger than FIFO depth
